# UIImage PNG conversion failure

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, phasset, uiimagepngrepresentation

I have an array of `UIImages` I am converting to PNG with `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. The `UIImages` are loaded from `PHAssets` from my photos library. Most convert without a problem, except for a few that will cause it to crash with the message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Printing the `UIImages` to the console reveals this difference between those that don't cause a crash and those that do:

```
result #0: <UIImage: 0x13a46c5b0>, {60, 45}  // this works
thumbnail #0 finished loading from lib
result #1: <UIImage: 0x13b133b00>, {60, 45}  // this too
thumbnail #1 finished loading from lib
result #2: <UIImage: 0x13a46d440>, {45, 60}  // this one causes a crash
thumbnail #2 finished loading from lib
result #3: <UIImage: 0x13a444790>, {60, 45}  // this one works
```

See the pattern? What do the numbers in the brackets mean? Any ideas on a fix? Thanks!

**UPDATE** 
I separated the unwrapping `array[i] as! UIImage` from the conversion and it works without a problem. It's definitely the conversion that's throwing the nil unwrapping error, even if I switch it to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

Comment: Maybe portrait and landscape. You need to show how you are converting it,  you are probably forcing to unwrap your object. the culprit is the exclamation mark

Comment: Yes, this is how I'm converting it: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!). But why would portrait/landscape make one of them nil of all things? The image still loads.

Comment: guard let image = image else { return }

Comment: Sure, if I'm expecting I might not get an image, but in this case I know that it's loading and it's there in the array.

Comment: sorry buddy but all I can say is that info looks like the image aspect ratio. And generally when saving PNG you may need to rotate the image prior to saving it